# declaring a friend function in the global namespace that returns a template class

Tags: c++, class, friend

i have a function declared in a namespace, that when it is defined as a friend, throws a compiler error.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Example
{
    std::vector<std::string> GetNames();
}

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass() : 
                name("data")
        {}

    private:
        std::string name;

    friend std::vector<std::string> ::Example::GetNames();
};
```

this fails to compile with the error

> 'Example' in 'class std::vectorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char >' does not name a type
> friend std::vectorstd::string ::Example::GetNames();
> ^~~~~~~
> main.cpp:25:2: error: expected ';' after class definition

yet if i remove the global namespace identifier, `::` from `::Example::GetNames()`, it will compile happily.

how do i deal with this issue when i need to start at the global namespace due to nested namespaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler doesn't evaluate your friend declaration as you intended it to. Instead, the compiler reads the following:

```cpp
    friend std::vector<std::string>::Example::GetNames();
```

It thinks that you want to declare the function `GetNames` that is within a namespace `Example` inside the `vector` class.
That's why when you remove the `::` the compiler can lookup the namespace `Example` itself and finds it in the global namespace.

What you want to do instead to tell the compiler that there is a global namespace called `Example` is to put parentheses around the function declaration:

```cpp
    friend std::vector<std::string> (::Example::GetNames)();
```

Now, this gets evaluated as you want to.

Comment: It's note worthy that this is essentially the same thing as differentiating `int (*foo)();` from `int* foo();`. Sometimes, the declarator syntax needs help disambiguating things.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica just as most human languages

Comment: yes, ignoring typos... and yes, i figured out that was what it was trying to do, but not how to avoid it.